Erro: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Visible' and no dict for setting new attributes
Estou tentando usar um programa que está em um arquivo ".bat", mas que foi escrito em python. o funcionamento desse programa é feito em 6 etapas, ou melhor dizendo, cada etapa é iniciada ao clicar em um dos 6 botões responsáveis por iniciar as funções.
Até semana passada, o programa estava funcionando normalmente, mas agora sempre que tento iniciar a terceira etapa, que é responsável por pegar uma planilha de Excel e gerar uma tabela dinâmica, ele me retorna "Erro: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Visible' and no dict for setting new attributes"
Essas são as bibliotecas usadas no programa:
tkinter,
datetime date,
datetime,
time,
tkinter as tk,
threading,
os,
pythoncom,
PyPDF2,
openpyxl,
tempfile,
win32com.client as win32,
sys,
pandas as pd,
time.
